# Scala invocation chaining

Tags: scala

Would you write:

```
(ontDrugFormXml \ "VPID").headOption map
    (id => graph.addE(vertex, searchDmdVertex(graph, "VMP", id.text), "has")) orElse
    (throw new IllegalStateException("VPID required"))
```

or:

```
  (ontDrugFormXml \ "VPID").headOption
    .map(id => graph.addE(vertex, searchDmdVertex(graph, "VMP", id.text), "has"))
    .orElse(throw new IllegalStateException("VPID required"))
```

Which one is proper to you?
Can't have the answer on http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
(ontDrugFormXml \ "VPID").headOption map { id =>
    graph.addE(vertex, searchDmdVertex(graph, "VMP", id.text), "has")
} orElse (throw new IllegalStateException("VPID required"))
```

The scala style guide requires infix notation for methods like `map` that take a function argument. Parameters should be on the same line as the opening brace, e.g. next to `map`. `orElse` should be one the same line as the value it takes.

Comment: With this one idea is complaining and wants to add a dot call for orElse

Comment: @Joan You're right, it needs another set of parentheses. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Infix, the first option. I always use infix notation for orElse.

Comment: I always use the latter. The former is harder to read past 1/2 methods or a DSL.